# Text is getting Meshed up in NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

I am facing this weird issue, where textview text is being meshed up. I have this screen under `NestedScrollView` with `match_parent` as width of `textview`. It happens when I switch between fragments.

[image: Original screen]

Buggy Screen

[image: Meshed up scren]
Did anybody face similar issue?